# Can't boot Windows after installing Windows 10 with Boot Camp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, macos, windows

I installed Windows 10 with Boot Camp Assistant in El Captain. I successfully completed all Boot Camp installation steps. After finishing the installation and rebooting the Windows boot option doesn't appear.

I tried this installation twice but without success. Partition is successfully created though.

How can I continue to get the Windows boot option?

**gpt/fdisk results**:

```
sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0

    start       size  index  contents
        0          1         PMBR
        1          1         Pri GPT header
        2         32         Pri GPT table
       34          6         
       40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
   409640  315141264      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
315550904    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
316820440   15625256         
332445696  157788160      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
490233856        863         
490234719         32         Sec GPT table
490234751          1         Sec GPT header


sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 30515/255/63 [490234752 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
        Starting       Ending
#: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  490234751] <Unknown ID>
2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Specs: Macbook Pro 13 Early 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. After remove *Paragon NTFS for Mac Software*, Boot Camp Windows options founded.

I think NTFS software for mac makes refusing to know window partitions.

Comment: I have the same problem, with the same machine that you have. But this didn't fix my problem. As i never installed the application which you mentioned. It may be some other one.

Answer (score 1):

This article might help: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204417

Section below:

Use these steps to choose a startup disk with Startup Manager:

1. Turn on or restart your Mac.
2. Immediately press and hold the Option
   key. After a few seconds, the Startup Manager appears. If you don't
   see the volume you want to use, wait a few moments for Startup
   Manager to finish scanning connected drives.
3. Use your mouse or
   trackpad, or left and right arrow keys to select the volume you want
   to use.
4. Double-click or press the Return key to start up your Mac
   from the volume you selected.